# Loop through possible values a class type

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

I'm learning how to use Python and [Basemap](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#module-mpl_toolkits.basemap) and would like to create a loop that produces a map of each `projection` type.

The projection types are: cea, mbtfpq, aeqd, sinu, poly, etc. So I just want a loop that does `Basemap(width=x, height=y, projection=[projection type], ...)` but can't figure out how to return the actual types of possible projections.

So far I've tried things like

```
proj = Basemap()
print(dir(proj))
```

and

```
proj = Basemap().projection
print(dir(proj))
```

but neither returns the types of projections it could be.  I tried

```
for value in Basemap().projection:
    print (value)
```

But it just returned

```
c
y
l
```

and that's it.

Closest I've gotten is

```
for value in Basemap().__dict__.items():
    print (value)
```

but that returns a ***lot*** of info, seemingly the default values, but one of them is `cyl`, which is the default projection.  I'm getting close but can't see how to iterate through each projection.

(My semantics are incorrect, so please correct me if I'm wrong!)

Edit: I'd like to learn how to do this without "cheating", i.e. since I know the types of projections possible, load those into an array and loop through the array. I'm trying to learn how to do it if I *didn't* know the possible values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to cheat; looking at [the source](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/blob/dd6d3f606aa72fe6addb8596669c9eb6f9a345bc/lib/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py#L98), you have a `supported_projections`  list that contains all supported projections. You can just use that.

Comment: Oh man, thanks for finding that! I was looking around forever.  For the record, all I needed to do was add `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import _projnames` then just do `for key, value in _projnames.items(): // print(key)`. I'm sure there's another way, without adding the possibly redundant `... import _projnames`, but doing like `for key in Basemap()._projnames.items()` was erroring out.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, what was I looking for? A "key" in a "class" type? The "values" of a "key" within a Class... just curious about the semantics for going forward.

Comment: @BruceWayne That really depends on how it is implemented. In general, information like this is either a class attribute or a module attribute. (I hope I'm understanding what exactly it is that's confusing you)